# setOnClickListener causes crash

Tags: android

```
Button start_game;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);          
    start_game = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_game);
    start_game.setOnClickListener(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
 }
```

I don't know why, but if I remove the line `setOnClickListener` my app starts (of course my button doesn't do anything then). 
Logcat gives me this:

> `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.test.testabc/de.test.testabc.Welcome}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: you are setting setcontentview() after findviewbyId()

Answer (score 8):

You have to inflate your layout **before** getting the UI elements, otherwise `findViewById` returns `null` and hence you got the `NullPointerException` at the line `start_game.setOnClickListener(this);`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    

    setContentView(R.layout.welcome); //layout inflated now it's ok to get your button

    start_game = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_game);
    start_game.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it still crashes:  03-17 12:48:02.567: E/AndroidRuntime(25368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 12:48:02.567: E/AndroidRuntime(25368): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.test.testabc/de.test.testabc.Welcome}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: @user3367856 You are certainly calling `setContentView` before `requestFeature()`. Don't do that.

Comment: I'm having requestWindowFeature to make it fullscreen, but this is after setconentView. Oh okay that's the problem THanks

Comment: @user3367856 That's what i'm saying. Call `requestWindowFeature` before `setContentView`. `requestWindowFeature` is the same as  `getWindow().requestFeature()`